# I'm getting a syntax error while running pip3

Tags: python, pip, package, version

when I run pip3 it crashes.

Here's what I get:

`ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:/var/www/html/pythonscrape$ pip3 --version
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/bin/pip3", line 7, in 
from pip._internal.cli.main import main
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/pip/_internal/cli/main.py", line 57
sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

One thing I'll add though, is that when I type the pip command, it shows that it is working for 2.7, however I do not want to use that version.

`ubuntu@ip-xxx-xx-xx-xx:/var/www/html/pythonscrape$ pip --version
pip 8.1.1 from /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (python 2.7)`

It looks like there is some kind of clash with the versions?

Should I even be using pip (i.e. not pip3) in python3?

Ultimately, my goal is to install bs4 for beautiful soup.

Comment: It looks like you have tangled up your Python versions somehow. You are running a version of `pip` for Python 3.6 or later (since it uses [f-strings](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0498/)) with an older version of Python that does not support them (the error message references Python 3.5). How did you install Python?

Comment: Side note: [Python 3.6 is end-of-life](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0494/). Unless there are other constraints, you should be using at least Python 3.7 in 2022.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpip%5D+sys.stderr.write%28f%22ERROR%3A+%7Bexc%7D%22%29

Comment: Hi guys, so I'll try that then, I'll just build a new server and install a newer version of Python.  Thanks so much for all your help.